# Change session mode to migrate to windows azure

Tags: session, azure, virtual-machine

I am hosting an on-premises website which I want to migrate to Windows Azure Virtual machine.I will be using multiple instances of Azure VMs. Currently I am using IN-Proc session management technique. Do I really need to change this session mode to migrate the website to cloud. Why??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have more than 1 Web Role Instance (for load balancing/scalability/redundancy purposes) then **Yes you do need to change it**. Just a reminder, but you need a minimum of 2 roles in order to be eligible for the 99.9% SLA.

`InProc` means that the session information is stored in that web roles process. a second web role instance, has no knowledge of that data contained in process in the first web role.

So if your first web request goes to WEBROLE_1 it has your session information.
If your second request goes to WEBROLE_2, it won't know that you already have some session data stored in the other role.

There are a number of other options for storing your session info including using TableStorage, SQL Azure or App Fabric Cache.

Comment: Instead of using App Fabric Cache, it is recommended that you use `Windows Azure Caching`. More information about storing session state in Windows Azure Caching can be found here: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/cache/#store-session